# Why a user can still delete object from S3 bucket even its policy has unchecked DELETEOBJECT property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created a user named **Test_User** and assigned it a direct policy which contains Access level permissions for all **S3** buckets but only unchecking **DELETEOBJECT** policy because I don't want the user to delete the object in the bucket.

Now the problem is that the **Test_User** can still delete the object in any bucket even though I have specifically unchecked the **DELETEOBJECT** in **WRITE** section.

Why?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:HeadBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "182.180.97.184"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can only think of three possibilities: the user already has this permission via another mechanism (bucket policy or another user/group policy)... or `s3:DeleteObjectVersion` allows this... or your policy originally allowed `s3:DeleteObject` and the change you made (to remove it) had not yet propagated when you were testing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I had to explicitly set DENY in it then it worked but the not the former way.

Comment: That should not be the case.  Everything is denied by default.  If a user can do anything, this means that you -- somewhere -- are granting it.  You really need to identify where that is happening.

Comment: If you **remove** this policy, are they still able to do things? That would be an indication that another policy is also in effect.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: i tried finding every policy but there is only one IAM policy being assigned to that user

Comment: The bucket policy can also grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

How about allowing s3:* then deny s3:deleteObject, deny overrides any allow statements.

It's not best practice though, really you should specifically scope out the role and only ALLOW the things it needs as everything is off by default.